# Set variable to result of promise

Tags: promise

This is more of a syntax/readability question. Let's say I have this:

```
  ProductsService.getProducts()
    .then(function (products) {
      model.products = products;
    }, function(){
      //handle error
    });
```

If the promise is resolved, I populate model.products with the result of the promise. Is there a way to organize this code so it's more like:

```
model.products = //result of promise
```

I prefer having the variable I'm setting front and center instead of having it buried in that promise.

Comment: That's fundamentally impossible.  You can't "escape" from asynchrony.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**In ES6 and below this is not possible.**

As an aside, in ES7 we can use [`await` in combination with an `async` function](https://jakearchibald.com/2014/es7-async-functions/) to achieve the type of 'readable asynchronous code' that you are looking for:

```
ProductsService.getProducts = async function() {
    // returns a promise...
};

model.products = await ProductsService.getProducts();
```

If you really are desperate to use it, [the functionality is available using Babel](https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/experimental/).

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
function setProduct(products) {
    model.products = products;
}

function foo(){
    return ProductsService.getProducts();
}

foo().then(setProduct);
```

But as said before, you have to wait for ES7 or use typescript/babel